# How to extend a class in netbeans at the time of class creating?

Tags: php, netbeans, ide

When we create a new class in netbeans I have to extend it manually if I have to, I want to extend the new class when it is being created using the New PHP Class dialog box.

Is there any plugin for Netbeans which could help to select a class as parent when creating a new class in "New PHP Class" dialog box in Netbeans 8.0.2 as shown below?

[image]